# How to find all the controls in WPF on a UserControl component

Tags: c#, wpf

I can get all UI controls on a `Form` but how to find controls on a certain `UserControl`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `Linq operator OfType` and `Controls property`

```
var controls = YourForm
               .YourUserControl
               .Controls.OfType<TextBox>();
foreach(var control in controls)
{
    ....
}
```

Link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/vstudio/bb360913.aspx

Comment: I used this but the ".Controls" turned red, why? It says, Cannot Resolve Controls

Answer (score 1):

You may have a look at the [FindName(string)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.findname.aspx) method of `UserControl`

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to look in the immediate object you can do [FindName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.findname.aspx):

```
object foundControl = someParentControl.FindName("nameOfChild");
```

or if you want recursive ways then you can look at this post here:
[How can I find WPF controls by name or type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/636383/wpf-ways-to-find-controls)

Comment: This is no good if you want *all* the controls and you don't care or know what their names are.